# How can I sort adjacent item with ui-sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jquery-ui-sortable

link: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable

If you will follow the link you will come to know that we can sort one item very nicely.

My case: suppose I have ten boxes (items from db) 1 to 10. Say in the first, 3rd, 5th and 7th items I have some flag (`superset == true`) then next item (adjacent) to it will be 2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th and 10th respectively.

I can drag any item but what I want is something like if I found 
`superset` flag in any item == true then not only that item should be draggable  but adjacent item should be draggable with it.

Meaning, if I drag 1st item and if that item has `superset == true` then next item to it should also be draggable with first item.

I found some hint form multiselction but for that, first I have to manually click on multiple items, which I do not want.

```js
myAppModule.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  var array = [{
      'item': 1,
      'superset': 'true'
    },
    {
      'item': 2,
      'superset': 'false'
    },
    {
      'item': 3,
      'superset': 'true'
    },
    {
      'item': 4,
      'superset': 'false'
    },
    {
      'item': 5,
      'superset': 'true'
    },
    {
      'item': 6,
      'superset': 'false
    },
    {
      'item': 7,
      'superset': 'true'
    },
    {
      'item': 8,
      'superset': 'false'
    },
    {
      'item': 9,
      'superset': 'true'
    },
    {
      'item': 10,
      'superset': 'false'
    }
  ];

  $scope.sortableOptions = {
    start: function(e, ui) { ...
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) { ...
    },
    update: function(e, ui) { ...
    },
  };
});
```

```html
<ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="array">
  <li ng-repeat="item in array">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

My code has feature like this but the code pasted here might have some bugs but on my end for me code is working fine. As expected form this plugin I can sort any item. I cannot paste actual code here that belongs a private organization.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or plunker with your current code?

Comment: code added please take  a look @NiK648